# dynamic topics with pub-sub with zmq, will that be fine?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I've read my docs most examples are for basic use cases.

Where simply one process publish X event and another subscribe to X event.

But in my applications X is kind of variable. so lets say i've X means my user.

so i can do publish from one server event like  `user-ID` means if i've 1000s of user connected to server so will that be Okay to publish and subscribe to so many dynamic topics, and then another 20 servers subscribe to that 1000s topics on this server.

Lets see the example.

i've 10 servers. each server with 1000 users connected. so total 10k users.
i need to send X data from each user to another user.

so i've did this.

X server publish `user-ID` data (1 publish user's who is connected, 1K publish)

Y server subscribe `user-ID` data (10k subscribe request to sent each server)

What should be optimal way of pub sub with dynamic topics so less bandwidth used among servers?

Notice::

user-ID is just an example where ID is dynamic number, and it publish some real time data which can't be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZeroMQ subscription matching is implemented in the PUB socket with a prefix-matching [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  This is a very efficient data structure, and I would expect that 10K subscriptions and 10K msg/sec would be no problem at all.

The PUB socket only sends messages for matching subscriptions (so there is no "waste").  If a message doesn't match any subscription then the PUB socket will drop it.  Matching messages are only sent to SUB sockets that have subscribed to them.

When you add or remove a subscription, the SUB socket will send a message its connected PUB socket(s).  Each PUB socket will then update its topic trie.

My guess is 10k subs and 10k msgs/s is no problem, but the best thing to do would be to write some test code and try it out.  Once nice thing about ZeroMQ is that it's not much work to test different architectures.

Comment: But someones said that only SUB socket store the list of subscription and PUB just multicast messaegs all SUBs even they are not subscribed.. and SUB filter all messages...

Comment: I think it worked like that in the past.  But my understanding is recent versions of ZeroMQ manage the subscriptions in the PUB socket.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know in pyzmq API publisher can send messages to any topic

```
socket.send("%d %d" % (topic, messagedata))
```

and subscribers set a filter on these topics for topic of their interests with `setsockopt`

```
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)
```

So I think you can fully implement your plan.

Comment: It's not my question..my question is bit about flow or optimum logic...will that be ok to have 10k publish call and 10k subscribe calls?

Comment: @dev.mraj 10k publish calls is ok, but what do you mean by 10k subscribe calls? 10k calls of setsockopt method or 10k clients? cause setsockopt is expensive.

Comment: @dev.mraj not at all)